# Why my prog fail?

Tags: c++, debugging

My codes are below:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int next(int n)
{
    return n + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int next(int);  // function declaration
    int *fp = &next;

    int temp = 10;
    temp = (*fp)(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;

    return 0;  
}
```

The complier points `int *fp = &next;` needs to be debugged, however, I don't find anything wrong with this sentence. 
Can you tell me? Thanks for your time~~

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Why? How to fix it?

Comment: It's declared as a pointer to an `int`. It needs to be declared as a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`. But I can't recall my function pointer declarations ATM.

Answer (score 8):

Function pointers are not defined like normal pointers

```
int (*fp)(int)
```

And your next function is already visible in main, no need to redeclare it

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
int (*fp)(int);  
fp = next;
```

Answer (score 3):

next is a function so where as *fp is a pointer to int not function.

## How to Fix

you dont need any pointers for this code. You can just write

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int next(int n)
{
    return n + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int temp = 10;
    temp = next(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int next(int n)
{
    return n + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int (*next)(int);   // function POINTER

    int temp = 10;
    temp = next(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to a function is not a pointer to an integer.